# Swift Generic Function Implementation Error: Cannot assign value of type 'X' to type 'X'

Tags: swift, generics

I've been implementing a CoreData stack that conforms to decodable. The general structure is like a book, eg there is a Book class which can have many chapters with the chapters each pointing to the book and the book pointing to all the chapters.

As part of this process, I've noticed a lot of boiler plate code and I am trying to combine some of the code. One thing I'm trying to do involves setting up the relations between these NSManagedObjects. For this I've created the following protocol (pardon the naming, still hashing out the details):

```
protocol RelatedManagedObject {
    func setRelation<T:NSManagedObject>(to object:T)
}
```

So that in my chapter class I would write:

```
func setRelation<Book>(to object:Book){
    self.book = object
}
```

However, I'm getting a compiler error at this point:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Book' to type 'Book'

It suggests force casting to 'Book' (eg `object as! Book`) but then yells at me to either remove the casting or add another one (`object as! Book as! Book`) LOL This is not going well.

Comment: Don't you just need `func setRelation(to object:Book)` ? `Book` has become your generic placeholder (The same as T is in your protocol definition)

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what I thought at first too. However, when I declared the function that way, I get another compiler warning stating that I've not conformed to the protocol.

Comment: Use T or anything other than Book. If you use Book you clash between the generic specifier and the clsss

Comment: @Jbryson Your chapter class breaks the liskov substitution principle. It needs to be able to accept any `T where T: NSManagedObject`, but it can only accept `Book`. While `Book` may be an `NSManagedObject`, there are other classes that conform to `NSManagedObject` that aren't supported (but need to be, for conformance)

Comment: You may want to use an associated type on the protocol rather than a generic argument to the method, but it's difficult to say without seeing more of what you're trying to do

Comment: @dan you had it right. I needed to add an associated type to the protocol. Works like a charm. If you want to write it up, I'll give you credit for the answer.